# dereferenced value of *argv[] not accurate

Tags: c++, pointers, argv

I'm trying to make a program that finds the largest prime factor of a given value.

If I run `./a.out 55`, `cout << "Input  " << *argv[1]<< endl;` returns 5 instead of 55.

When I take out the asterik and check the pointer `value(argv[1]) I get 55. I'm confused why this is happening.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        cout << "Input  " << *argv[1]<< endl;
        // cout << "Biggest Prime Factor of 34 is : " << findPrime(number, 0) << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Too many inputs:" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `*`:

```
cout << "Input  " << argv[1] << endl;
                    ^
```

It's because `*argv[1]` means the first character of `argv[1]`. You want the entire string instead.

Comment: I am slightly confused. Isn't argv an array of char pointers, not array of chars?

Comment: @wayfare Yes, but `argv[1]` itself is a `char *`. Thus, `*argv[1]` is a plain `char`.

Comment: so shouldn't argv[1] return the address not the actual characters?

Comment: @wayfare It *does* evaluate to an address. What makes you say that ?

Comment: ohhhh I just realized something and now it all makes sense! lol. thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply:

- `argv[1]` is the C string containing the first argument;
- `*argv[1]` is the first character of that string.

If the latter is confusing, note that `*argv[1]` is equivalent to `argv[1][0]`.

In summary, you want:

```
cout << "Input  " << argv[1]<< endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

argv is pointer to array of chars.

Then you do e.g. `argv[0]` you get table of chars - e.g. some text.

So you don't need to place asterisk before `argv[0]` if you want to get text hidden under `argv[0]`.